# Why is prior useEffect() still running for a significant amount of time even after the component is rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm implementing stopwatch in ReactJs this is how my code looks as of now:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
  const [isPaused, setIsPaused] = useState(false);

  const secondsToTimerFormat = (seconds: number): string => {
    console.log(seconds)
    return (seconds-seconds%60)/60+":"+seconds%60
  }

  const manipulateTimer = (toPauseTimer: boolean) => {
    setIsPaused(toPauseTimer);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!isPaused){
      setTimeout(() => {
        setSeconds(seconds + 1)
      }, 1000)
    }
  }, [seconds, isPaused])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {secondsToTimerFormat(seconds)}
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => {manipulateTimer(true)}}>Pause</button>
        <button onClick={() => {manipulateTimer(false)}}>Resume</button>
        <button onClick={() => {
          setSeconds(0);
        }}>Reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm expecting this to work normally. But the "Reset" button is not working as expected.
If I click on "Reset" after 13 seconds, this is the `console.log()` output.

[image: 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 0, 14, 1, 15, 2, 16, 3, 17, 4, 18, 5...]

If I add a new variable inside `useEffect()`, say something like `let execute: boolean = true` and then set it to `false` in `useEffect()` clean up, everything is working as expected.

So, I know the fix, but I want to know the reason behind the current behaviour. I understand that when I click on reset, there is already a `useEffect()` running with seconds value as `13`. But since its `setTimeout()` ends in one second and at the same time, I'm doing `setSeconds(0)`, why would the previous `useEffect()` run multiple times before coming to halt?

Answer (score 1):

Issues like this usually arise because the timers being used are not being cleared between renders. Also, when the next state depends on the current state, it is better to use the second form of the state setter function which takes the current state as the parameter and returns the next state. Modify the useEffect as given below to get this to work:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let timer;
    if (!isPaused) {
      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        setSeconds((seconds) => seconds + 1);
      }, 1000);
    }

    return () => {
      if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
    };
}, [seconds, isPaused]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setInterval` and separate methods for handling the timer state:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
  const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState(0);

  const secondsToTimerFormat = (seconds) => {
    console.log(seconds);
    return (seconds - (seconds % 60)) / 60 + ":" + (seconds % 60);
  };

  const handleStart = () => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds((prev) => prev + 1);
    }, 1000);
    setIntervalId(id);
  };

  const handlePause = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    handlePause();
    setSeconds(0);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {secondsToTimerFormat(seconds)}
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            handlePause();
          }}
        >
          Pause
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            handleStart();
          }}
        >
          Resume
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            handleReset();
          }}
        >
          Reset
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/cold-tdd-etp6nw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) to sandbox